# Implement a Queue of commands

Tags: c++, buffer

I have a ring buffer in which I want to place some bytes received over serial port. Now these received bytes consist of a command followed by data bytes. And each of these command and data combination could be off different length. I want to implement a method in which I can copy one command from this buffer and execute it. Then the next command and so on. What would be the best (and simplest) way of doing it?

Comment: what's your problem, you need to show what you have done.

Comment: *What would be the best (and simplest) way of doing it?* -- "Best" and "simplest" are all subjective.

Comment: Encapsulate your command using a TLV struct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tlv

Answer (score 0):

Simple byte stream will do. Actually, you can even use a wrapper over `std::stringstream` for your byte stream as a storage as a first step: fill it with the routine that communicates with the serial port and read from it with the instruction decoder.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about ring buffer it can be something as simple as char[ring_size_in_bytes] and current location indicator int.  Reading from port should be byte by byte and when you reach end of the buffer you start from zero.

I usually use simple buffer for command and for data read from port. After copying data from port to small buffer I interpret data on the fly trying to find beginning of command and then start putting to buffer until I detect new beginning. Then I enqueue command and start over. This constitutes top half (fast one) of serice routine.

Serial port is very slow so there is no risk that you will not read data from it fast enough. Each iteration (interrupt) will give you couple of bytes ...

I would use queue of type that encapsulates your commands to store received commands list.

How complicated is your serial protocol ?